# Two Partitions Versus Two Disk Drives

Tags: partitioning, disk

What is the difference between two operating systems on two different partitions on the same disk versus two operating systems on two different disk? What is the jargon for each case? What can one do which the other cannot do? For example can you run two disks at the same time, but not two partitions at the same time?

When people talk about two operating systems on the same computer, I cannot tell if they are referring to two partitions on the same disk, or two separate disks.

Comment: You answered your own question. A disk drive is sub divided into part , or partitions. So if you install 2 OS onto a single disk drive, each OS needs it's own partition + swap. Or you install each OS on it's own drive, and each os has one partition. Of course you can subdivide further is you desire, such as a /home or a data partition, whatever you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes absolutely no difference from the user's perspective. Whether the two OS's partitions are on the same disk or not is irrelevant. The jargon is exactly what you used, *two different disks* means two separate physical disks and *different partitions* could be either on the same disk or on separate ones.

The only difference from a practical perspective is that if you have two separate disks and one of them dies, the other will not be affected. However, it is perfectly possible that (depending on the type of failure) a particular partition gets corrupted and another on the same disc is unaffected. In fact, short of catastrophic hardware failure, problems in a single partition should not affect the others.

In any case, you will only ever be able to run a single operating system at a time. Again, this has nothing to do with whether the OSs are installed on different disks or not. You can, however, have your data spread across multiple drives and access it at the same time with no problem. For example, this is the setup of my home server:

```
$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.4T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   9.8G  0 part /media/Data
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   1.2T  0 part /mnt/sda3
├─sda5   8:5    0  46.6G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0    14G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0 117.4G  0 part 
└─sda8   8:8    0   2.3G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0  29.3G  0 part /
├─sdc2   8:34   0 428.4G  0 part /home
└─sdc3   8:35   0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/sdb1
```

In the output above, I have 3 disks with 12 different partitions. As long as they're mounted, I can write/read data to and from any of them without any problems.

In short, just use whichever you want. The differences are not very important.

Comment: Could you provide more technical explanation on why two disks cannot dual run two os on the same computer? I have very little understanding of computer architecture, but I see two disks as two different computers connected to the same monitor. Why is this not the case? Thanks.

Comment: @linuxfreebird nothing technical about it. The hard disk is most certainly not the computer in any sense. It's only a storage medium. You can have computers (and indeed did, for many years) with no hard drive at all. The _computer_ is the [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit). You can think of hard drives as books and of the computer as your brain. You can have many books but can only read one at a time. In the same way, computers can have multiple operating systems installed but only one can be used at the same time.